# Cómo recoger el valor de un select SQL PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Estoy realizando un sistema de logs con PHP, SQL y MySQL, y quiero que el registro que vaya a guardar la información de cada ejecución del programa tenga el mismo id (las operaciones no se hacen todas a la vez, sino secuencialmente). Para ello, y para que haya orden en la tabla, he de coger el último id que haya en la tabla y sumarle uno, para luego cuando haga las operaciones indicarles que hay que actualizar datos en ese registro.
El código que tengo ahora mismo es el siguiente:

```
$id=0;

//CONSIGO EL VALOR DEL ID, COGIENDO EL ÚLTIMO ID DE LA BBDD Y SUMÁNDOLE UNO


$sql="SELECT `id` FROM `logs_articulos_api_csv` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1";
$resultado=mysqli_query($conWebService, $sql);

var_dump($resultado);

if($resultado){
    echo "Se ha recogido el id de forma correcta";
} else {
    echo "No se ha recogido el id de forma correcta";
    echo $sql ."\n". mysqli_error($conWebService); 
}
```

La pregunta es... ¿Cómo asigno el valor recogido en el `SELECT` a la variable `$id`? Porque imprimo el resultado en pantalla y me sale lo siguiente:

```
object(mysqli_result)#2 (5) {
  ["current_field"]=>
  int(0)
  ["field_count"]=>
  int(1)
  ["lengths"]=>
  NULL
  ["num_rows"]=>
  int(1)
  ["type"]=>
  int(0)
}
```

Vale, es un array, pero... ¿cómo puedo asignarle el valor correcto a `$id`? Gracias, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Lo conseguí, finalmente con este código:

```
//GENERO EL ID PARA EL REGISTRO DE LOGS

$id=0; //Inicializo la variable id

$sql="SELECT `id` FROM `logs_articulos_api_csv` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1"; //Cojo el id del último registro
$resultado=mysqli_query($conWebService, $sql);

if($resultado){
    echo "Se ha recogido el id de forma correcta";  
    $idarray=mysqli_fetch_row($resultado); //Lo recojo como array
    $idstring=implode("", $idarray); //Lo paso a string
    $idint=intval($idstring); //Lo paso a int
    var_dump($idint);

    $idfinal=$idint+1; //Ya como int, trabajo con él y le sumo un +1 para el nuevo registro

    echo "El id es:".$idfinal;

    $sql="INSERT INTO `logs_articulos_api_csv`(`id`) VALUES ($idfinal)"; //Lo inserto en la BBDD para trabajar con este id en esta ejecución del programa.
    $resultado=mysqli_query($conWebService, $sql);
} else {
    echo "No se ha recogido el id de forma correcta";
    echo $sql ."\n". mysqli_error($conWebService); 
}
```

El `$resultado` es un array, de modo que si quieres tenerlo en int, deberás usar `implode()` para pasarlo a string y luego `intval()` para pasarlo a int. Saludos.